# How do I find out if a .exe is running in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, executable

How can you find out if an executable is running on Windows given the process name, e.g. program.exe?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Do you want to know if the program was written in C++? Or do you want to know if a particular program by name `program.exe` is currently running on your operating system (OS)?

Comment: @Byron; I think only MS-OSes uses the .exe-extension, no? So my guess is Win2000 or above, which yields pretty much the same answer I suppose.

Comment: @jacob  i mean im programing a program in c++ and i want it to see if a .exe is running

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ standard library has no such support.  You need an operating system API to do this.  If this is Windows then you'd use CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(), followed by Process32First and Process32Next to iterate the running processes.  Beware of the inevitable race condition, the process could have exited by the time you found it.

Comment: Note: CreateToolhelp32Snapshot will not operate as expected in some cases; it often reports the wrong number of svchost.exes. :/ It should be fine for most uses though.

Comment: @blood: this was a "this is the way to do it on Windows" answer.  Your "there has to be a way" response is puzzling and defies any attempt to come up with a better answer.

Comment: o sorry i did not read it right i thought he said it would not work in most cases :D sorry

Answer (score 5):

I just created one using Hans suggestion.  Works like a champ!

Oh and here is the basic code.

Please you will have to add CStrings sAppPath and sAppName.

StartProcess is a small function that uses CreateProcess and returns the PID(not used here). You will need to replace it.

This is not a complete program, just the code to find if the program is running using Hans suggestion.  A fun test is to set the path to c:\windows\ and the app to notepad.exe and set it for 10 seconds.

```
#include <tlhelp32.h>
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = {0}; 
HANDLE    hSnap;
int       iDone;
int       iTime = 60;
bool      bProcessFound;

while(true)    // go forever
{
    hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32); 
    Process32First(hSnap,&pe32);     // Can throw away, never an actual app

    bProcessFound = false;   //init values
    iDone = 1;

    while(iDone)    // go until out of Processes
    {
        iDone = Process32Next(hSnap,&pe32);
        if (strcmp(pe32.szExeFile,sAppName) == 0)    // Did we find our process?
        {
            bProcessFound = true;
            iDone = 0;
        }
    }

    if(!bProcessFound)    // if we didn't find it running...
    {
        startProcess(sAppPath+sAppName,"");             // start it
    }
    Sleep(iTime*1000);    // delay x amount of seconds.
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment since this does not answer the question. Although this question is quite old and doesn't even remotely add anything to it, you shouldn't have even posted anything.

Comment: Added the code Falmarri.  I really didn't think it was that big of deal.  Just trying to give credit.

Comment: Beware of the memory leak in this code: `hSnap` needs to be released with `::CloseHande`

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: since you mention '.exe', you want this for some flavor of Windows. You want to write a program in C++ to determine whether a program with a particular executable name is running (regardless of the language used to implement the target program).

Enumerate the running processes using either the Toolhelp API or the process status API. Compare the name of the executable for each running process to the one you're looking for (and be aware that there may be more than one process with that executable name).

Answer (score 0):

```
hProcessInfo = OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID );

            do{
                if(strcmp(pe32.szExeFile,"process.exe") == 0)
                {
                    processfound = true;
                    break;
                }
}while( Process32Next( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) );
```

If you don't want to get process detail from code just press Ctrl+Alt+Del and check process list.

Comment: If this is "tested code", maybe the test result was negative? It'd be rather surprising if this worked, given that there's no call to `Process32First`.

Comment: My guess is that you have done a modified snippet of the above example, but it's not clear of how to use it. Please provide a FULL example that works.