# How to check if a process is running or not using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I should not display  certain context menu options if one process is not running?.
I am checking if the process is running or not using the process name.

But the issue is, the process name is showing different way in different windows platforms.

ie, windows 64 bit process name on windows task bar is " **applicationname.exe**"

some windows xp machine shows the same process name as "**applica~2.exe**"

Please let me know the  consistent way to check if the process is running or not?

My development environment is C++ and Visual Studio 2010

```
   DWORD getProcessID(const std::wstring& processName)
   {
       PROCESSENTRY32 info;
       info.dwSize = sizeof(info);

       HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
       if ( snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
             return 0;

       Process32First(snapshot, &info);
       if ( !processName.compare(info.szExeFile) )
       {
             CloseHandle(snapshot);
             return info.th32ProcessID;
       }

       while ( Process32Next(snapshot, &info) )
       {
              if ( !processName.compare(info.szExeFile) )
               {
                    CloseHandle(snapshot);
                    return info.th32ProcessID;
               }
       }

      CloseHandle(snapshot);
     return 0;
   }
```

Comment: This is windows specific, yes? You should add a tag.

Comment: thanks BobTFish, I will remember this next time.

Comment: Have you tried using `Module32First`? See description beneath `szExeFile` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find if a .exe is running in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355379/how-to-find-if-a-exe-is-running-in-c)

Comment: Globally, or just in the current user context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EnumProcesses` is the other way to enumerate active processes.

The difference is that you need to allocate the space for PIDs,call `EnumProcesses`, open each process with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` access flag and then call `GetProcessImageFileName` on it's handle and do the comparison.

Comment: a good example is here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using WMI to interrogate instances of [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows you to check the fullpath of the running processes for a match on the one you need to see.

Answer (score 0):

Are you the author of the process in question? If so, a more robust design would be to use IPC to interrogate the process directly. That way, you don't necessarily have to poll and you don't have irritating issues such as what happens if you detect the process, create the context menu and then the process goes down?

Comment: Adding IPC rarely makes a process more robust without substantial effort, esp. if the sole purpose is to achieve things the OS already allows, like process monitoring. Every new IPC channel is a security exploit waiting to happen.