# Getting compilation error for "tlhelp32.h" in MinGW g++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, windows, process, header-files

I am writing a simple C++ app that checks whether a given exe file example:'a.exe' is running or not(windows OS), I have googled and found some code in the below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355379/how-do-i-find-out-if-a-exe-is-running-in-c

The code mentioned above uses a header file "tlhelp32.h". I just copied the code and  did some necessary changes then complied it in MinGW , there comes the next problem, all of the datatypes mentioned in that header files are errored out 
`ex: 'DWORD' does not name a type, 'LONG' does not name a type, 'WCHAR' does not name a type,'CHAR' does not name a type`

I never faced this kind of issues before where an existed header file is failed to compile (yes it exist I've checked it).

really appreciate any help on this.

code below:

```
#include <tlhelp32.h>


int main()
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = {0};
HANDLE    hSnap;
int       iDone;
int       iTime = 60;
bool      bProcessFound;

while(true)    // go forever
{
    hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    Process32First(hSnap,&pe32);     // Can throw away, never an actual app

    bProcessFound = false;   //init values
    iDone = 1;

    while(iDone)    // go until out of Processes
    {
        iDone = Process32Next(hSnap,&pe32);
        if (strcmp(pe32.szExeFile,"a.exe") == 0)    // Did we find our process?
        {
            bProcessFound = true;
            iDone = 0;
        }
    }

    if(!bProcessFound)    // if we didn't find it running...
    {
        startProcess("C:\\MinGW\\"+"a.exe","");             // start it
    }
    Sleep(iTime*10);    // delay x amount of seconds.
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: `#include <windows.h>` before `#include <tlhelp32.h>`

Comment: Critten!!!!!!! what an effective answer many thanks it does work now no error like before  and if you don't mind may i know why is that, because i am new to this concepts and i also want to know any websites that could eloborate how we can deal with process in c++

Comment: @RichardGeorge - If you program for Windows, `#include <windows.h>` is generally a good idea.  :-)  An obvious starting point for info on that would be Microsoft's [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Got it  Pearson,after I finished fixing the above said issue I have gone through MSDN to understand what exactly the code does and learn some bunch of things from that.thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Richard Critten said adding "Windows.h" before "tlhelp32" resolves the issue and more over a function startprocess() in the above code has never existed so use shellexecute() to make it work

ex: ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "c:\MinGW\a.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);