# It said there's something wrong with the header file, mmsystem.h, i can't use PlaySound()

Tags: c++, header-files, playsound

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "winmm.lib")

using namespace std;

int main() {
    PlaySound(TEXT("Happy Birthday To You.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\mmsystem.h|905|error: 'DWORD' does not name a type|
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\mmsystem.h|906|error: 'UINT' does not name a type|
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\mmsystem.h|907|error: typedef 'UINT' is initialized (use decltype instead)|

It just came up tons of the errors in the header file like these, I linked to `-lwinmm` and checked the library, it still pops up.

PS I am using code blocks.

Comment: are you even using int main tho

Comment: @Isaac I did. I just show the parameter part at here.

Comment: You need to include `windows.h` **before** `mmsystem.h`.

Comment: `windows.h` should be first in your includes. `mmsystem.h` uses types defined in `windows.h` (including DWORD and UINT).

Comment: @KenWhiteThank you I didn't realize the header files need orders

Comment: i guess its a good introduction to dependencies

Comment: @Gavin.G *Good* header files include everything that they need. But Sturgeon was wrong about our field, *far* more than 90% of codebases are crap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting compilation error for "tlhelp32.h" in MinGW g++ compiler: DWORD does not name a type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943646/getting-compilation-error-for-tlhelp32-h-in-mingw-g-compiler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `windows.h` **before** `mmsystem.h`. `windows.h` should be first in your includes. `mmsystem.h` uses types defined in `windows.h` (including DWORD and UINT).